# Компиляция C/C++ вместе с Python

Tags: c++, python, c

Программа написана на С, часть кода на python.

Как скомпилировать программу, чтобы она работала без интерпретатора?

Comment: "Компиляция" python кода это фактически сборка исходников (возможно в байт-коде) на питоне и самого интерпретатора в один исполнимый файл. Если это вас устраивает, то гугл на запрос "python компилятор" выдает нужное...

Comment: Про запаковку питона в exe я знаю, вопрос не в этом, вопрос в том что программа написана на С с элементами кода на python, если я просто скомпилирую С, то программа будет требовать интерпретатор python для работы, как этого избежать? как правильно собираются программы написанные на С и на python ?

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч  Что значит "часть кода" ?  Если основная программа написана на C значит есть вызов интерпритатора питона , Если основная программа написана на питоне то есть модули на писаные на С.

Comment: Приведите минимальный но полный пример кода в котором часть c++, часть python. [mcve] Общий Питон код требует интерпретатора во время исполнения (который можно в ваш процесс встроить (embed), если хотите). Некоторые подмножества Питон кода могут быть скомпилированы и напрямую без runtime зависимости.

Comment: У меня только один вопрос `Зачем?`.

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч, почему удалил вопрос про flask? Мог бы ответ на свой вопрос написать, мне вот интересно, в чём там проблема...

Comment: @diraria проблема была в том, что я значением куки указывал число, а нужно сроку

Comment: Понятно. Ну так восстанови вопрос и напиши ответ, может кому-нибудь пригодится.